# ffmpeg rtmp stream taking 100% CPU

Tags: ffmpeg

I am creating a small script to stream a images on rtmp server but FFMPEG command taking 100% CPU. Please have a look on my code.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -loop 1 -i "Digital-Wallet-.jpg" -t 00:30:00 -r 1 -c:v  libx264 -c:a aac -preset:v ultrafast  -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv "rtmp://rtmpserver"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encoding is CPU intensive. Remove `-r 1` and add `-framerate 1`, `-re`, and `-shortest`.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -loop 1 -framerate 1 -re -i "Digital-Wallet-.jpg" -t 00:30:00 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -preset:v ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -f flv "rtmp://rtmpserver"
```

- The default image demuxer frame rate is 25, so your command was unnecessarily converting 25 frames per second to 1 frame per second which is inefficient. The above changes fixes that.
- `-re` will slow down the reading of the input to the native frame rate of the input. It is useful for real-time output and live streaming. Otherwise `ffmpeg` will attempt to encode as fast as possible.
- I added `-shortest` to end the output when the shortest stream ends (the image) because anullsrc was set to encode indefinitely.

Comment: one more question, do you know how can we compile FFMPEG for android?

Comment: @RaviKumar Sorry, I don't know. Probably many FFmpeg on Android compile questions/answers on this site.

Comment: I have one problem. I want to stream a video file over rtmp and that video file will be continuously updated with new content. Do you know how can we achieve that? please help...